# Could there more than one variable in an elementary function?

Tags: terminology

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) defines an elementary function as

> a function of **a single variable** that is defined as taking sums, products, and compositions of finitely many polynomial, rational, trigonometric, hyperbolic, and exponential functions, including possibly their inverse functions

while [Wolfram's definition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunction.html) doesn't claim it has to be a function of **a single variable**.

So, could there more than one variable in an elementary function?

Comment: do you consider $f(x, y) = x + y$ to be elementary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources I have seen use a definition consistent with a single variable. As for the wolfram link, I think the wolfram definition is suggestive of defining the term for a single variable since it refers to inverses and repeated compositions (though this phrasing technically allows for the possibility of self maps on $\mathbb{C}^n$).

The question then becomes: Why can't we call more functions "elementary"? This question is explored [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/836556/why-cant-we-define-more-elementary-functions/836574). Of course, nothing is stopping us from calling other functions, such as polynomials in several variables, "elementary." The question is: How useful is it to do so?

For instance, our defined notion of "elementary functions" enjoys application in differential algebra. These functions are closed under differentiation, but not under antidifferentiation. [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) gives an answer to which kind of elementary functions have elementary antiderivatives, and the [Risch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) makes this theorem practicable.

Comment: Thank you. So, the ellipse area formula doesn't count as an elementary function, right?

Comment: @JJJohn What formula? You mean the function $f(a,b)=\pi a b$, the area of an ellipse?

Comment: Yes. Is the guy $f(a,b)=\pi a b$ an elementary function or not?

Comment: @JJJohn Not sure why that in particular; it is one of infinitely many polynomials in two variables. But again, in keeping with the single variable characterization of an elementary function, I would not call that "elementary."